# Which Windows IMAP client should I use for plain-text emailing?

Tags: windows-7, email-client, plain-text, imap

At my job we have switched from Lotus Notes to Office 365, which is an improvement, but being used to Gmail I'm not perfectly happy using Outlook or the Outlook web app.

I am looking for a Windows email client that **must**:

- run on Windows 7
- support IMAP
- have threaded conversation view, including sent messages
- have awesome plain text editing capabilities, including easy editing of quotations - should be able to increase/decrease quotation level for a block of text
- have message labelling, not just folders, so that a message can exist in multiple labels (as in Gmail)
- have great search/indexing capabilities

Other nice-to-haves:

- Good filtering capabilities (not strictly necessary, as I can set up filtering in the Outlook web app)
- Auto or scheduled archiving of old mail in my inbox
- Be able to thread messages by subject, not just by the `Message-ID` header

This is what I have tried so far:

- [*The Bat!*](http://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/) - its threaded conversation view does not include messages from my *Sent* folder, so threads only show messages I have *received*.
- [*Mozilla Thunderbird*](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) - same threading problem as *The Bat!*. With the [Thunderbird Conversations extension](https://github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/wiki), it threads messages by subject (good).
- [*Opera Mail*](http://www.opera.com/no/computer/mail) - my favourite so far. Does not support threading by subject.

The problem with all these is their plain text editors. I receive a lot of badly formatted emails. When replying to an email, I want to quote parts of the previous messages, and I want it to be clear what I have quoted and who wrote it. None of the clients I have seen has any methods for manipulating quotation level, for example turning this:

> This block is quoted from an earlier message. I want to increase its quotation level

into this:

> > This block is quoted from an earlier message. I want to increase its quotation level

Some email clients, like Thunderbird with the [External Editor extension](http://globs.org), allows me to use an external editor for plain text editing. This might work for me, if I can find a text editor with the required email editing features.

So what email client should I use?

Comment: i can't tell since when, but for quite a while now Thunderbird also shows sent messages in the threaded view. **||** maybe also a really interesting add-on for conversations is [**ThreadVis**](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/threadvis/).